# loginscreen after standby wrong keyboard layout

Tags: suspend, keyboard-layout, 17.10

I have an annoying problem: On my clean install (17.10) the login screen (after boot) had a wrong keyboard layout which I could change with dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration.
But after I put my laptop into sleep closing the lid the login again has the wrong layout.

Now comes the really mysterious part: When I use set xkbmap to set the layout, close the lid, wait a few seconds till I see the indicator blink, stating that the laptop fell into sleep, open the lid again, then the login screen has the right layout set. But when I wait longer, e.g. 30 minutes, before opening the laptop again, the layout is wrong again.

I have no clue how to analyze nor to solve this.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the output of these commands: 1. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` and 2. `cat /etc/default/keyboard`. Also, what does "use set xkbmap to set the layout" mean? Please explain more exactly how you do it. Possibly there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks. I meant, that I executed "set xkbmap ch".  `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` gives:
`[('xkb', 'ch')]` and `cat /etc/default/keyboard` :
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
XKBMODEL="thinkpadz60"
XKBLAYOUT="ch"
XKBVARIANT="de_nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch"
BACKSPACE="guess"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have only the `ch` layout both system wide and in the desktop configuration, and I can't really explain the behavior you describe.

One thing I would have tried, if I was you, is to open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and change the line

```
XKBLAYOUT="ch"
```

to

```
XKBLAYOUT="ch,us"
```

and reboot.

That would set the US English layout as an alternative, which makes a keyboard layout indicator show up at the top right of the screen. That way, if you at some point find that an incorrect layout is effective, you can use the indicator to get it right.

Comment: Thank you, good idea, but unfortunately not successful: On my login screen after boot I now have the indicator for the layout as expected. But my login screen after suspend does not show the indicator. It only shows the wifi- , the sound- and the battery-icon. When I bring up the onscreen keyboard I see the us layout but still cannot switch.

Comment: @McSvenster: It would be good if you could file a bug report about it against the gdm3 package.

Comment: Thanks again for your hints! I filed the bug report as [Bug #1727980](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1727980)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I cannot reproduce this anymore - seems to have been a local problem. 
Here is what I did to solve it: I reset the whole gnome config:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

then changed the layout to "de" and then back to "ch-de". Now it works as expected.